# Error when previewing MICE pooled regression results

Tags: r, rstudio, r-mice

I have run into a simple, but somewhat annoying issue in RStudio and I am curious if there's a fix. The problem occurs with objects that contain pooled regression results obtained through MICE imputation. When I type the object's name, as soon as RStudio suggests an autocomplete and tries to display a preview of the data object (as it now does since a recent update), I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 4
```

This is strange because if I am fast enough to type out the full name and hit enter before RStudio can show a preview, there are no issues. I can also print out the object and work with it without any issues.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
library(mice)
mydf <- iris

# create some NAs
l <- nrow(mydf)
set.seed(1)
indeces <- sample(1:l, l/3)
mydf$Sepal.Length[indeces] <- NA

# impute data with 30 variations
m <- 30
mydf_mice <- mice::mice(data=mydf, m=m, maxit=10, seed=1, print=F)

# create models for imputed data
# (I know that you can also do this using 'with()', but the code below works ok for me)
mydf_mice_models <- lapply(1:m, function(i) {
  lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width,
     data = mice::complete(data = mydf_mice, i))
})

# look at the results
mydf_mice_models_pooled <- mice::pool(mydf_mice_models)

# PROBLEM OCCURS HERE: try typing the object name
mydf_mice_models_pooled
```

No issues here:

[image]

But an error pops up as soon as `mydf_mice_models_pooled` gets previewed:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug with the IDE. You can file it [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a bug with a software.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'll head over there to discuss this issue